# System.Data.SQLite BadImageFormatException with NHibernate, works finewhen standalone

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, x86, badimageformatexception, typeloadexception

I tried to use NHibernate with SQLite,
version=1.0.74.0 for .NET 4 and 32 bit.
I use a 64bit WIN7, but build the application in x86 mode 
(default in VS2010 express).

When I use the same SQLite as a standalone application it works fine, but when
I try to use it with NHibernate it throws `BadImageFormatExcepion`

I debugged a bit NHibernate and the Exception is thrown at the folllowing statement

```
System.Type.GetType("System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite");
```

Any chances somebody knows the solution?
Is it because I use default mode in VS Express?
Do I need to specify platform using some other method?
try to download some other dll for sqlite?

I checked some other answers on SO thebest I got was
to add to my app.config this:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>



 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

Answer (score 2):

If VS express does not allow you to choose a platform you can try setting it up manually in .csproj file

```
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
```

After building your app make sure that:

- it is executed as 32 or 64 bit app depending on what you put in PlatformTarget (using Windows Task Manager or Process Explorer)
- the right version of **SQLite.Interop.dll** is copied to the folder where you have your exe (this dll is platform dependent, so you need to copy the version corresponding to EXE platform)
- Corresponding version of **Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package** is installed

Also try removing `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy` from config.

From [BadImageFormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) doc:

> ... A DLL or executable is loaded as a 64-bit assembly, but it contains
>   32-bit features or resources. For example, it relies on COM interop or
>   calls methods in a 32-bit dynamic link library. ... To address this exception, set the project's Platform target property to x86 (instead of x64 or AnyCPU) and recompile.